# Duplicate columns in Spark Dataframe

Tags: r, csv, hadoop, apache-spark, sparkr

I have a 10GB csv file in hadoop cluster with duplicate columns. I try to analyse it in SparkR so I use `spark-csv` package to parse it as `DataFrame`:

```
  df <- read.df(
    sqlContext,
    FILE_PATH,
    source = "com.databricks.spark.csv",
    header = "true",
    mode = "DROPMALFORMED"
  )
```

But since df have duplicate `Email` columns, if I want to select this column, it would error out:

```
select(df, 'Email')

15/11/19 15:41:58 ERROR RBackendHandler: select on 1422 failed
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) : 
  org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'Email' is ambiguous, could be: Email#350, Email#361.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:278)
...
```

I want to keep the first occurrence of `Email` column and delete the latter, how can I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best way would be to change the column name upstream ;)

However, it seems that is not possible, so there are a couple of options:

1. If the case of the columns are different("email" vs "Email") you can turn on case sensitivity:

   ```
        sql(sqlContext, "set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true")
   ```
2. If the column names are exactly the same, you will need to manually specify the schema and skip the first row to avoid the headers:

   ```
   customSchema <- structType(
   structField("year", "integer"), 
   structField("make", "string"),
   structField("model", "string"),
   structField("comment", "string"),
   structField("blank", "string"))

   df <- read.df(sqlContext, "cars.csv", source = "com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true", schema = customSchema)
   ```

Answer (score 6):

You can add a simple line when you start a spark session, after successfully create spark session add this line to set spark config...

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "true")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming the column.

You can select it by position instead of the `select` call.

```
colnames(df)[column number of interest] <- 'deleteme'
```

Alternatively you could just drop the column directly

```
 newdf <- df[,-x]
```

Where x is the column number you don't want.

**Update:**

If the above don't work, you could set header to false and then use the first row to rename columns:

```
  df <- read.df(
    sqlContext,
    FILE_PATH,
    source = "com.databricks.spark.csv",
    header = "FALSE",
    mode = "DROPMALFORMED"
  )

#get first row to use as column names
mycolnames <- df[1,]

#edit the dup column *in situ*
mycolnames[x] <- 'IamNotADup'
colnames(df) <- df[1,]

# drop the first row:
df <- df[-1,]
```

Comment: I tried both, but they all lead to the same "Reference 'Email' is ambiguous" error I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a new dataframe using `toDF`.

Here's the same thing, for pyspark: [Selecting or removing duplicate columns from spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205113)