# Duplicate columns in spark read json

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I ran `spark.read.json(json_file_path)` on a json file with a flat structure.

I got the error message:

```
Reference 'col' is ambiguous, could be: col#29582L, col#29632
```

It is possible that this is due to another column with a name of different case : `Col`. How could this be resolved if I cannot modify the json data?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After referring to the [R case of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816481/duplicate-columns-in-spark-dataframe) and searching for the configurations.

I found

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "true")
```

from https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/15/how-to-use-sparksession-in-apache-spark-2-0.html