# In Spark 1.6 , How to read a CSV file with duplicated column name

Tags: apache-spark

I am unable to find a solution for reading a CSV file which has a column name repeated twice but while reading the CSV file it's giving an error complaining duplicate column names

Is there a way to handle this in spark without altering the CSV file ?.

My CSV data looks like this delimited by Tab (\t) & some extra spaces in each column.

```
col1    col2  col3
  2020  100   sometext
```

Comment: you can provide a custom schema

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, If i provide custom schema, it complains me of data validation errors . Any idea why it's like that ?.

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816481/duplicate-columns-in-spark-dataframe

Comment: something like  this even if data types are correct due to spaces i guess --> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "   20511"

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021073/spark-sql-removing-white-spaces for dealing with such space issues

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I tried those 2 options to ignore leader/trailing whitespaces. Still same NumberFormatException

Comment: update the question with input samples, your tryings and the error message please

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using textfile method to read csv files and then convert them to DF or use them as RDDs after splitting and mapping them back!

Hope this works!