# Selecting or removing duplicate columns from spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given a spark dataframe, with a duplicate columns names (eg. `A`) for **which I cannot modify the upstream or source**, how do I select, remove or rename one of the columns so that I may retrieve the columns values?

`df.select('A')` shows me an ambiguous column error, as does `filter`, `drop`, and `withColumnRenamed`. How do I select one of the columns?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I found with hours of research is to rename the column set, then create another dataframe with the new set as the header.

Eg, if you have:

```
>>> import pyspark
>>> from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
>>> 
>>> sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
>>> sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
>>> df = sqlContext([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], ['a', 'b', 'a'])
DataFrame[a: bigint, b: bigint, a: bigint]
>>> df.columns
['a', 'b', 'a']
>>> df2 = df.toDF('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> df2.columns
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

You can get the list of columns using `df.columns` and then use a loop to rename any duplicates to get the new column list (don't forget to pass `*new_col_list` instead of `new_col_list` to `toDF` function else it'll throw an invalid count error).